# xpages - enableModifiedFlag -> possible to prevent default dialog at beforeunload event?

Tags: xpages

For my xpages app I want to set the enableModifiedFlag to true to have a dirty form functionality to check if changes are made to a page.

I tried to avoid that the default warning message will appear when moving away from the page by setting the page to not dirty but this not prevent/hinder that the default dialog appears. what am I doing wrong?

```
window.addEventListener('beforeunload',(event) =>{
    var isdirty = XSP._isDirty();
console.log("check -> is dirty? " + isdirty);
if(XSP._isDirty()){
    console.log("set dirty to false to avoid ugly standard alert dialog");
    XSP._setDirty(false,"");
    
    //add this to prevent default behaviour e.g. open another page
    event.preventDefault();
    
    //add here code to present a more fancy bootstrap dialog
    //XSP.openDialog("dirtyDialog")
    
    return false;
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Haven't done exactly what you do...

However, if on a button you want to "cancel" then you only need to call

```
XSP._setDirty(false,"");
```

prior to navigating away. No need to call event.preventDefault() in that case. So I'm guessing that the default code is called prior to your "before unload" event - perhaps you can try and see if you could intervene a little before or somehow rethink the approach.

Perhaps I don't fully understand what you want to obtain when having this functionality but avoiding to use it when leaving the page - or is this just a test example?

/John

Comment: users can navigate away via buttons, links, back button.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense... Have you tried to investigate the other events to see if it makes a difference? And even try the above code on a button to see if that does as you want - just as a starting point?